# VLC get current playing time from video filter and add marks on seek bar

Tags: c++, video, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to write video filter plugin that will draw rectangles on specific frames due to coordinates written in another loaded file.

But I've reached some problems during working on it, so want to ask:

1. Is it possible to get current playing time inside video filter? (I can count the frames, but it won't work if the user scrolls to another position on the seek bar; also there is parameter date in the input picture_t, but as I see it corresponds only for displaying time so that the pictures processed too long can be skipped).
2. Is it possible to get title and path to the playing video from the video filter plugin or any other and how to combine such plugins to reach my goals.
3. How to set marks under the seek bar (like chapters) to show the corresponding changes we'll make in the video(Highlight the positions/frames we'll going to transform)

I'm noob in VLC and C/C++ programming, so sorry if my questions are very simple, nevertheless couldn't find the solution elsewhere. Would appreciate any help.Thank's.